# Good patterns to access the user who made a change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, actionmailer, grails-controller

in my app there are couple of reasons to know who made a change, which can produce a notification.

For instance if I assign a task to someone, the model's after_update can produce a notification, but I don't want it to produce one if I assign something to myself.

For that I am currently using `User.current`, that does Thread lookup `Thread.current[:current_user]`. An alternative would be to tell the model who is saving them and there maybe other alternatives too.

What are the approaches you've used or seen successfully implemented in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem. Where you can view all versions of your model:

```
@your_model.versions # => []
@your_model.whodunnit # => will be filled your current_user of an action
```

Or set user before perform saving:

```
PaperTrail.whodunnit = 'Manager'
```

There are many options for [doing it](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change).

Comment: Very nice example for when using versioning, thanks! Any alternatives you used without paper_tral? I am not interested in versioning every model that I need notifications for at the moment.

Comment: You will use PaperTrail for target model only if you set method for this model: has_paper_trail. Also you can create own logic for it. One way to do it is to create separate model, i.e. OrderTransition with fields(:from_name, :to_name, :user_id, :user_name, etc.). And create methods for every transions, e.g. OrderTransion.done!